# Installing Django in a virtualenv with paramiko

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, pip

I am using paramiko and create some virtualenvs over ssh like so:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, SSHConfig

def ssh_connect(self):
    # ssh config file
    config = SSHConfig()
    config.parse(open(settings.SSH_CONFIG))
    o = config.lookup('my_key')

    # ssh client
    ssh_client = SSHClient()
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh_client.connect(o['hostname'], username=o['user'])
    return ssh_client

def create_virtualenv(self):
    ssh = self.ssh_connect()
    venv_path = '/srv/virtualenvs/%s' % self.domain
    cmd = 'virtualenv %s' % env_path
    stdin = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    self.create_database()
    ssh.close()
```

Now I ran into a bit of a wall here because I want to also install Django into this newly create virtualenv with pip. I tried a postmkvirtualenv hook because I do have virtualenvwrapper installed on that server but that does not seem to run when I create a new environment using the code above.

Can anyone give me any hints as to how I can install Django in this manner?

Comment: Is it for deployment automation? Have you considered tools like [ansible](http://ansible.github.com/)? [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) and [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) are also popular choices if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Not for automated deployment, we have an internal system for our employees and this would simply be for launching a new environment due to lack of access to that server, I just want to simply create the environment for them over ssh like above.

Comment: @JeffC That's exactly what Ansible does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the **workon** command? This command is part of virtualenvwrapper and allows you to activate a given virtualenv, you should be able to do something like this:

```
def create_virtualenv(self):
    ssh = self.ssh_connect()
    venv_path = '/srv/virtualenvs/%s' % self.domain
    cmd = 'workon %s; pip install Django' % env_path
    stdin = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    self.create_database()
    ssh.close()
```